# Clojure :pre report failing value when destructuring

Tags: error-handling, clojure, preconditions

Following this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24834116/how-can-i-get-clojure-pre-post-to-report-their-failing-value), I would like to print the value of the preconditions in my function. However it fails for me in the following case (probably destructuring) :

I have a `dir?` helper function (feel free to skip this one) :

```
(defn dir? [s]
  "returns true if the string passed is is an existing directory"
  (->> (clojure.java.io/file s)
       ((juxt #(.exists %) #(.isDirectory %)))
       (every? true?)))
```

It works just fine, and using the `is` macro, I get some nice error messages where I can see both the test and the parameters that were passed :

```
(is (dir? (io/file "resources/static"))) ;; => true

(is (dir? (io/file "resources/statice"))) ;; typo, error below
```

> FAIL in clojure.lang.PersistentList$EmptyList@1
>   (boot.user4515592986834245937.clj:86) expected: (dir? (io/file
>   "resources/statice"))   actual: (not (dir? #object[java.io.File
>   0x6730a420 "resources/statice"]))

However, when trying to use it in the precondition `:pre`, I get an ugly error :

```
(defn make-something
  [&{:keys [dir]
     :or {dir "default-dir"}}]
  {:pre [(is (dir? (clojure.java.io/file dir)))]}
  ;;... do something with these
 )

(make-something :dir "resources/statices") ;; doesn't exist
```

> clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.AssertionError:
>   Assert failed: (is (dir? (io/file dir))),
>   compiling:(boot.user4515592986834245937.clj:80:12)
>                  java.lang.AssertionError: Assert failed: (is (dir? (io/file dir)))

How can I get a nice error message in my function just like the one above ?

In case it matters, I am using Clojure 1.7.

Comment: The "nice" error message should be printed in the stdout.

Comment: memfn was depricated pre clojure 1.0, the #(.isDirectory ...) form is more normal now

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt oh interesting, I did not see that anywhere. Where did you get that info ? It is not in the source https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.7.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L3717

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check your code (`dir?` function). Following snippet works for me:

```
(require '[clojure.java.io :as io])

(defn dir? [s]
  (let [dir (io/file s)]
    (and (.exists dir)
         (.isDirectory dir))))

(defn make-something
  [& {:keys [dir] :or {dir "default-dir"}}]
  {:pre [(is (dir? dir))]}
  (println dir))

(make-something :dir "/tmp")
out => /tmp
ret => nil

(make-something :dir "/xxxx")
FAIL in clojure.lang.PersistentList$EmptyList@1 (form-init3332271312167175068.clj:1)
expected: (dir? dir)
actual: (not (dir? "/xxxx"))

AssertionError Assert failed: (is (dir? dir))  user/make-sth (form-init3332271312167175068.clj:1)
```

Comment: It is because I edited the code by hand after Arthur's comment. Your code now works in my REPL so I accepted your answer (Clojure 1.8 though - I haven't tested with 1.7 as in my original question).