# Meaningful error message for Clojure.Spec validation in :pre

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

I used the last days to dig deeper into **clojure.spec** in Clojure and ClojureScript.

Until now I find it most useful, to use specs as guards in `:pre` and `:post` in public functions that rely on data in a certain format.

```
(defn person-name [person]
  {:pre [(s/valid? ::person person)]
   :post [(s/valid? string? %)]}
  (str (::first-name person) " " (::last-name person)))
```

The issue with that approach is, that I get a `java.lang.AssertionError: Assert failed: (s/valid? ::person person)` without any information about **what exactly did not met the specification**.

Has anyone an idea **how to get a better error message** in `:pre` or `:post` guards?

I know about `conform` and `explain*`, but that does not help in those `:pre` or `:post` guards.

Answer (score 12):

In newer alphas, there is now `s/assert` which can be used to assert that an input or return value matches a spec. If valid, the original value is returned. If invalid, an assertion error is thrown with the explain result. Assertions can be turned on or off and can even optionally be omitted from the compiled code entirely to have 0 production impact.

```
(s/def ::first-name string?)
(s/def ::last-name string?)
(s/def ::person (s/keys :req [::first-name ::last-name]))
(defn person-name [person]
  (s/assert ::person person)
  (s/assert string? (str (::first-name person) " " (::last-name person))))

(s/check-asserts true)

(person-name 10)
=> CompilerException clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Spec assertion failed
val: 10 fails predicate: map?
:clojure.spec/failure  :assertion-failed
 #:clojure.spec{:problems [{:path [], :pred map?, :val 10, :via [], :in []}], :failure :assertion-failed}
```

Comment: It would have been nice to be able to use s/assert or s/explain* in the pre: and :post "hooks" too...

Comment: You can use them in pre and post?

Comment: Nothing happens when I have this (failing) s/assert in `(defn f [x] {:pre [(s/assert string? x)]} (println x)) ` But s/explain do capture it so that is fine for me. ( 1.9.0-alpha13 )

Comment: Do you have assertions enabled? You'll need to either call https://clojure.github.io/clojure/branch-master/clojure.spec-api.html#clojure.spec/check-asserts or to set the clojure.spec.check-asserts system property to enable them.

Comment: You are right. (s/assert) works with assertions enabled. My problem originated from me mixing up `(s/assert string? x)` with `(assert string? x)` (from clojure.core). The latter needs to be written `(assert (string? x))` to kick in.

Comment: @AlexMiller the link describing check-asserts now 404s, but it is described here: https://clojure.org/guides/spec#_using_spec_for_validation

Comment: Updated link: https://clojure.github.io/spec.alpha/clojure.spec.alpha-api.html#clojure.spec.alpha/check-asserts

Answer (score 6):

I think the idea is that you use `spec/instrument` to validate function input and output rather than pre and post conditions.

There's a good example toward the bottom of this blog post: http://gigasquidsoftware.com/blog/2016/05/29/one-fish-spec-fish/ .  Quick summary: you can define a spec for a function, including both input and return values using the :args and :ret keys (thus replacing both pre and post conditions), with `spec/fdef`, instrument it, and you get output similar to using `explain` when it fails to meet spec.

Minimal example derived from that link:

```
(spec/fdef your-func
    :args even?
    :ret  string?)


(spec/instrument #'your-func)
```

And that's equivalent to putting a precondition that the function has an integer argument and a postcondition that it returns a string.  Except you get much more useful errors, just like you're looking for.

More details in the official guide: https://clojure.org/guides/spec ---see under the heading "Spec'ing functions".

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Will try that.

Comment: This will not check return values though, so instrument only replaces :pre. The idea is you use test.check to test that your functions map input to output correctly. Then you instrument and test your functions in integration through normal tests. Finally, you use s/assert wherever you want production guards, such as mentioned in Alex Miller's answer.

Comment: :ret values can also be instrumented using orchestra. https://github.com/jeaye/orchestra

Comment: I strongly recommend using orchestra as @xtreak said.  If you run a `repl/refesh` as part of a [reloaded](http://thinkrelevance.com/blog/2013/06/04/clojure-workflow-reloaded) workflow, don't forget to re-instrument all your fns every time.  Pair orchestra with [expound](https://github.com/bhb/expound) for fast, pretty failures.

Answer (score 2):

Without taking into account if you should use pre and post conditions to validate function arguments, there is a way to print somewhat clearer messages from pre and post conditions by wrapping your predicate with `clojure.test/is`, as suggested in the answer below:

[How can I get Clojure :pre & :post to report their failing value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24834116/how-can-i-get-clojure-pre-post-to-report-their-failing-value)

So then your code could look like this:

```
(ns pre-post-messages.core
  (:require [clojure.spec :as s]
            [clojure.test :as t]))

(defn person-name [person]
  {:pre [(t/is (s/valid? ::person person))]
   :post [(t/is (s/valid? string? %))]}
  (str (::first-name person) " " (::last-name person)))

(def try-1
  {:first-name "Anna Vissi"})

(def try-2
  {::first-name "Anna"
   ::last-name "Vissi"
   ::email "Anna@Vissi.com"})

(s/def ::person (s/keys :req [::first-name ::last-name ::email]))
```

Evaluating

```
pre-post-messages.core> (person-name  try-2)
```

would produce

```
"Anna Vissi"
```

and evaluating

```
pre-post-messages.core> (person-name  try-1)
```

would produce

```
FAIL in () (core.clj:6)

expected: (s/valid? :pre-post-messages.core/person person)

  actual: (not (s/valid? :pre-post-messages.core/person {:first-name "Anna Vissi"}))

AssertionError Assert failed: (t/is (s/valid? :pre-post-messages.core/person person))  pre-post-messages.core/person-name (core.clj:5)
```

Comment: I'm not to sure about requiring test `clojure.test` namespace in production code. But this seems to be a viable option, to get meaningful message from `:pre` guards.

Comment: @DiegoFrings The problem with `clojure.test/is` expressions in production code seems to be a bit special: Actually running the tests (via `lein test`) messes up the counters. Not only are the `is` expressions in the `deftest` expressions counted toward the test pass/fail totals, but any `is` called by production code is counted too. Otherwise, one could consider `clojure.test/is` as just another function returning boolean, generating output written via the overridable `clojure.test/report`. After all, one can use e.g. Hamcrest matchers in production Java code too, not only in JUnit classes.

Answer (score 2):

This is useful when you don't want to use `s/assert`, or can not enable `s/check-assserts`. Improving on MicSokoli's answer:

`:pre` simply cares that the values returned are all truthy, so we can convert the return value `"Success!\n"` to `true` (for strictness) and `throw` an error with the explanation and the input data in case the output is not successful.

```
(defn validate [spec input]
    (let [explanation (s/explain-str spec input)]
        (if (= explanation "Success!\n") 
            true
            (throw (ex-info explanation {:input input}))))
```

A variation of this could be this one, but it would run the spec twice:

```
(defn validate [spec input]
    (if (s/valid? spec input) 
        true
        (throw (ex-info (s/explain spec input) {:input input}))))
```

Usage:

```
(defn person-name [person]
  {:pre [(validate ::person person)]}
  (str (::first-name person) " " (::last-name person)))
```