# clojure test that assertion throws

Tags: clojure, clojure.test

I have a function defined as:

```
(defn strict-get
  [m key]
  {:pre [(is (contains? m key))]}
  (get m key))
```

And then I have a test for it:

```
(is (thrown? java.lang.AssertionError (strict-get {} :abc)))
```

However this test fails:

```
  ;; FAIL in () (myfile.clj:189)
  ;; throws exception when key is not present
  ;; expected: (contains? m key)
  ;; actual: (not (contains? {} :abc))
```

What is needed to check that the assertion would throw an error?

Comment: Isn't there redundant `is` in the body of the precondition? try change it to `{:pre [(contains? m key)]}`

Comment: @OlegTheCat well spotted! I am using this trick from there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24836592/1327651
I guess I have to choose between tests and useful REPL errors.

Comment: From Clojure 1.9 you don't have to chose. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37885542/meaningful-error-message-for-clojure-spec-validation-in-pre

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your assertion fails because you are nesting two `is`.  The inner `is` already catches the exception so the outer `is` test then fails because nothing is thrown.

```
(defn strict-get
  [m key]
  {:pre [(contains? m key)]} ;; <-- fix
  (get m key))
```

---

```
(is (thrown? java.lang.AssertionError (strict-get {} nil)))
;; does not throw, but returns exception object for reasons idk

(deftest strict-get-test
  (is (thrown? java.lang.AssertionError (strict-get {} nil))))

(strict-get-test) ;; passes
```